# Split vector to equal-overlapping sub-vector length when the sub-vector length is even or odd

Tags: r, split

Given a vector of `vec <- 1:n` and `l` to be the subvector length, I want an `R` function that breaks a vector into subvectors. This `R` function works When `l` is even number.

```
splitWithOverlap <- function(vec, seg.length, overlap) {      
  starts = seq(1, length(vec) - 1, by=seg.length-overlap)
  ends   = starts + seg.length - 1
  ends[ends > length(vec)] = length(vec)  
  lapply(1:length(starts), function(i) vec[starts[i]:ends[i]])
}
## try the function
vec <- 1:17
l <- 6
ov = ceiling(l/2)
splitWithOverlap(vec, l, ov)
```

The problem is when `l` is odd number such that the half-way can not be found. The solution to the odd number of `l` case can be solve by telling `R` to alternate between `ov = ceiling(l/2)` and `ov = ceiling(l/2) - 1` such that I will have result like **Figure 2** or **Figure 4**.
[image: Picture to show my desired output]

Comment: If you just need to switch between `ceiling(l/2)` for even and `ceiling(l/2)-1` for odd, you could move the calculation of overlap into the function, and use modulo to check whether  `l` is even or odd. `l%%2==0` is TRUE for even numbers.

Comment: Abetter demonstration, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the starts and ends given the `len` and `ov` (overlap) listed below each figure and `n`, the number of x's.  In the output `start[i]` is the start of the ith block and `end[i]` is the end of the ith block.

```
blocks <- function(len, ov, n) {

  starts <- unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, len), seq(len-ov+1, n, len))))
  ends <- pmin(starts + len - 1, n)

  # truncate starts and ends to the first num elements
  num <- match(n, ends)
  head(data.frame(starts, ends), num)
}
```

Using the inputs listed below the figures in the question we can double check that it does indeed give the correct starts and ends for each block:

```
fig1 <- blocks(len = 2, ov = 1, n = 17)
str(fig1, vec.len = Inf)
## 'data.frame':   16 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ starts: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
##  $ ends  : num  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
      
fig2 <- blocks(len = 3, ov = 2, n = 17)
str(fig2, vec.len = Inf)
## 'data.frame':   11 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ starts: num  1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11 13 14 16
##  $ ends  : num  3 4 6 7 9 10 12 13 15 16 17
          
fig3 <- blocks(len = 4, ov = 2, n = 17)
str(fig3, vec.len = Inf)
## 'data.frame':   8 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ starts: num  1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15
##  $ ends  : num  4 6 8 10 12 14 16 17
      
fig4 <- blocks(len = 5, ov = 3, n = 17)
str(fig4, vec.len = Inf)
## 'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ starts: num  1 3 6 8 11 13
##  $ ends  : num  5 7 10 12 15 17

fig5 <- blocks(len = 6, ov = 3, n = 17)
str(fig5, vec.len = Inf)
## 'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
## $ starts: num  1 4 7 10 13
## $ ends  : num  6 9 12 15 17
```

Comment: can you tell me what you answer does?

Comment: Have added more description.  I don't know why someone downvoted this but it gives the precise same blocks as the figures in the question.

Comment: I begin to see the beauty of your work, can you show the `starts` and `ends` will produce the desired result?

Comment: I thought that the crux of the problem was the starts and ends as shown in the figures in the question and the rest was already clear from the code in the question but if not then use this code to get a list of interval contents: `b <- blocks(l, ov, length(vec)); 
with(b, Map(function(i, j) vec[i:j], starts, ends))` where `l`, `ov` and `vec` are as in the question.

Comment: please tell me what `n`, `len` and `l` stand for?